# JavaScript toggle class on current element

Tags: javascript

Just want to understand a principle of JavaScript, I'm a bit new to this.

I'm adding some styling to some element which are slides which I'm scrolling through.

The "current" `div` have a `transform: none` applied, the two others get styled depending on where I am on the slider.

I'm using this code which is working fine.

```
el.style.transform = i === e.current ? 'none' : i > e.current ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(-100%)'
```

My question is how do I add / toggle a `class` to the current `el`, and remove it back when it's not the current anymore.

I've tried some couple options using the same principle but can't find the right way to achieve it.

```
el.classList = i === e.current.toggle('classname') : i > ? e.current.toggle('classname')

el.classList.toggle() = i === e.current ? 'active' : i > e.current ? 'prev' : 'next'
```

Can somebody give me a heads up on how to achieve what i want to do? I've tried to go through some others post on Stack Overflow and to look on `element.classList` docs everywhere i could find it, but I'm stuck at this point and JS knowledge is not my strong point.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code efforts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: @Dipakchavda. You want to have a look at all my attempts on how to achieve it ? Most of them are not on my code anymore, as i'm testing then delete them on the fly. I do know how to add/toggle/remove a class through javascript. i've tried to toggle class on the current element, but the only thing it's doing is indeed toggle the class but on all my el, not just the el which is the current one.

Comment: I mean to say , just post whole code so we can give solutions of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toggle takes the class name e.g. `el.classList.toggle('classname')`. You don't pass a variable to a function like this `el.classList.toggle() = 'classname'`. But you might be better off calling `add` or `remove` depending on if the item is the current one since you also need to ensure the other classes aren't still there.

```
el.classList[i === e.current ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
```

However since you also want `prev` and `next` probably best not to try and be too clever with ternaries and make it readable:

```
if (i > e.current) {
  el.classList.remove('current', 'prev');
  el.classList.add('next');
} else if (i < e.current) {
  el.classList.remove('current', 'next');
  el.classList.add('prev');
} else {
  el.classList.remove('prev', 'next');
  el.classList.add('current');
}
```

If you aren't worried about overwriting other classes you could simplify this using `className` as it overwrites any existing classes:

```
if (i > e.current) {
  el.className = 'next';
} else if (i < e.current) {
  el.className = 'prev';
} else {
  el.className = 'current';
}
```

Comment: you're the man. Everything work as expected. Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it. I think i tried to much trying to replicate that using the code i was using to add styling, but yes, checking if the class is present using a simple condition did the trick. thanks again.

Comment: Np glad it helped!